# Select records that don't exist in another DB table

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I'm trying to tackle what I thought was a simple query.

I have two databases each with one table in the DB.

What I would like to do is find all of the emails from DB1.Table that don't exist in DB2.Table

I'm using this query, but the result is incorrect because I know DB1.Table contains emails that don't exist in DB2.Table (result always comes back as 0)

`SELECT DB1.20180320.email
   FROM DB1.20180320 
   WHERE DB1.20180319.email NOT IN 
   (SELECT DB2.20180319.email FROM DB2.20180319 WHERE Status = 'active')`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? I'm working with about 80k rows in each table.

Thanks.

Comment: select a.* from a exception join b on a.id = b.id  /* all records in a that are not in b by id */  Good Luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without seeing your data, try something like this.

```
SELECT DB1.20180320.email
   FROM DB1.20180320 
   left join DB2.20180319 on DB1.20180320.email = DB2.20180319.email 
           AND DB2.20180319.Status = 'active'
   WHERE DB2.20180319.email IS null;
```

This should show all the emails in DB1.20180320 that don't exist in DB2.20180319

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked perfectly (and query executed quickly).

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS` query should do it.  It returns email that exist in DB1, but not DB2.

```
SELECT DB1.20180320.email
FROM DB1.20180320 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM DB2.20180319 
    WHERE DB1.20180320.email = DB2.20180319.email 
        AND DB2.20180319.Status = 'active'
)
```